# The requested PHP extension ext-mysqli * is missing on php 7.2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysqli

when I

```
composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

I got the problems:

```
- The requested PHP extension ext-mysqli * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysqli extension.
```

I had edit my php.ini and restart the php and nginx but still show the error?

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx

sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

Do I need to install another mysqli? It's so strange. I had install the
sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm php7.2-mysql php7.2-cgi php7.2-common php-pear php7.2-mbstring
before and work well. But I don't know why it has the problem when I reinstall the ubuntu and mariaDB and php 7.2 and phpmyadmin.

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the question by installing

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm php7.2-cli php7.2-mysql php7.2-gd php7.2-imagick php7.2-recode php7.2-tidy php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-common php7.2-curl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml php7.2-bcmath php7.2-bz2 php7.2-intl php7.2-json php7.2-readline php7.2-zip
```

But I don't know why?

Comment: probably because of `php7.2-mysql`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when I enabled the MySQLi extension,
Enable MySQLi extension in php.ini, just uncommented this line in php.ini

> extension=php_mysqli.dll

This is the php.ini file path

> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

This problem mainly occurs because by default MySQLi extension is disabled in PHP 7.x

Comment: I use nginx and my php.ini is show on my question! I had uncomment the extension=mysqli the line.

Comment: php 7.2 is different from the php 7.0